# How can i merge my local changes with the repository changes in github?

Tags: github

I am new github user. I am working on a repository. I got the repository command by

git clone SSHPATH

git fetch origin

Now I have made some changes in my local code and wish to check in those changes. However, the same files have changed during this time period and have been pushed to the repository by some other user. How can I merge my changes with the repository changes and check in the code?

Can someone tell me the commands? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Regards
Aparna

Answer (score 0):

The normal workflow would be that you fetch the commits done remote to your local repository first. You can perform any necessary merging locally without affecting the remote repo. Once you are finished, just push to origin.

So it's basically a `git pull origin master` to pull remote changes into the local repo. Any conflicts need to be resolved here. Git will prompt you to do that when necessary (but it is rather smart to resolve many conflicts on its own). After that, just `git push origin master` to upload the merged changesets.

Comment: Thanks Holger. I tried this out , and found that git pull origin master returned a message of Fast Forward. 49 Files changed, 150 insertions, 333 deletions. However, my files on local repository were not changed. Any idea what fast forward implies? Do we need to provide some option with git pull?

Comment: Also along with some files a symbol S was appearing.